# Excel vba: Why doesn't the screen update, update cells right before turning off screen updating

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that starts with calling another sub (that edits the workbook's cells) and then turns off screen updating and alerts. The thing is, even though the first sub that edits the workbook is located before the second sub, the cell isn't updated.

When I turn off the second sub, the cell is updated. How can I update the cell and then turn off the screen updating?

```
Sub mainSub()
        Call editSub 'edit cell's value: ThisWorkbook...Cells(i, j).Value=...
        Call setupApp 'turns off scren updating, when uncommented prevents the previous sub from getting visible results
        ...
End Sub

Sub setupApp()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Screen updating is **already** true when the `mainSub` starts; Commenting the `setupApp` sub out **helps**, because it obviously gets executed earlier than the cells are edited somewhy.

```
Sub editSub()
    Dim resultArray() As String
    resultArray = getStateNames()  'just returns an array of Strings

    displayStateNameArray (resultArray)
End Sub

Sub displayStateNameArray(resultArray As Variant)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("C6:C97").Clear
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For k = LBound(resultArray) To UBound(resultArray)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(5 + i, 3).Value = resultArray(k)
            i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: is there an Application.ScreenUpdating = False in getStateNames?

Comment: @Moosli No there's not

Comment: Ok, lets go to a Caht. You can see it at the Comments in my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't get why this is not working. 
But you could try to call the SetupApp with a If Statement. For that you have to cahnge the editSub to a Function and at the end just return a true Value. Something like this:

```
Sub mainSub()
        If editSub = True Then Call setupApp
End Sub

Sub setupApp()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

Function editSub() As Boolean
'Code stuff in her
editSub = True
End Function
```

---

**Second Solution**

You can try to Force the Events with `DoEvents` to update the Screen.

Like this:

```
Call editSub 
DoEvents
Call setupApp
```

Or you Put the DoEvents right after you have written in the Cells.

---

If this don't work, you could try the Wait Method:

```
Application.Wait "00:00:01"
```

---

---

**First Solution**

Have you tryed to turn the ScreenUpdating on Before Execut the Sub?

```
Sub mainSub()
            Call setupApp(true)
            Call editSub 'edit cell's value: .Cells(i, j).Value=...
            Call setupApp (false)'turns off scren updating, when uncommented prevents the previous sub from getting visible results
            ...
    End Sub

    Sub setupApp(bol as Boolean)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = bol 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = bol 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Screen updatin is **already** true when the sub starts. Commenting the second sub **helps**, because it obviously executes earlier than needed.

Comment: How much code is in editSub? Becuase if there are only a few lines, it can be that the UpdateEvent is to slow and it will be turnd off before Updating the Screen

Comment: Quite a few lines. It takes some data, checks it, adds to array and only then edits the cells with values from array.

Comment: @Ans Ok, i addited my Awnser

Comment: Unfortunatelly neither helps..... Waiting just results in longer execution time, while the cells are still empty, the `DoEvents` doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153264/discussion-between-moosli-and-ans).